Electric potential in a circuit
I am a high school student and have recently learned about electrostatics. According to our textbooks, electric potential of a point  is defined as the work done on a unit charge by an agent against the electric force. But in case of current electricity in a circuit, we still use potential of a point of a circuit. Now,in this case, how can a charge be brought from infinity to calculate the potential of a point in a circuit? And how the potential of a electric source like battery is fixed?

"Now,in this case, how can a charge be brought from infinity to calculate the potential of a point in a circuit? "  I don't see how a circuit changes the story.  Are you having trouble doing the math to compute the potential, or are you unsure of what it means to do work on a unit charge in the presence of a circuit?

The typical description of the electrical potential at a point is the work required to bring a positive charge from infinity to that point.  But the assumption there is the potential at infinity is zero. In reality, the potential at any point can be arbitrarily assigned a value of zero and then the potential at any other point is the work required to bring a positive charge from the point assigned a zero value to the point in question.
The latter is the case in a circuit. Some point is arbitrarily assigned a value of zero (typically the negative terminal of a battery). Then the potential at every other point in the circuit is calculated with respect to that zero point. So one doesn't typically come from infinity in assigning potentials in circuits.
What really matters is the potential difference between points and that doesn't matter where the point is assigned a potential of zero.

And how the potential of a electric source like battery is fixed?

The potential at any point in a circuit, including the terminal of a battery, depends on the point in the circuit that has been assigned a potential of zero, which as indicated above is arbitrary. So there is no unique value of the potential at a point in a circuit, including a battery terminal.  But as indicated above the potential difference between points in a circuit, including between the terminals of a battery, does not depend on the point in the circuit assigned a potential of zero.
What is unique about the potential difference between the battery terminals is that, in the case of an ideal battery (one with no internal resistance), unlike a resistor it doesn't depend on the current through the battery. I've emphasized the term "ideal", because real batteries have internal resistance across which there is a voltage drop when the battery delivers current. That effects the terminal voltage. On the other hand, the internally generated battery voltage, the battery emf, is constant as long as the battery chemistry can sustain it.
Hope this helps.

Thanks a lot for your answer, it solved my confusion.

Bob D gave a good answer to the first part of your question. I'll just answer this part:

And how the potential of a electric source like battery is fixed?

It's not the potential of the battery that is fixed, it's the potential difference between the two terminals of the battery.
It's fixed by the chemical reaction that is going on in the battery to separate charge, removing electrons from one electrode (the cathode) and depositing them on the other (the anode). Once the potential difference between the two electrodes reaches a certain point, the chemical reaction stops. If the potential difference later drops (for example, because a current was drawn from the cathode and returned to the anode) then the chemical reaction starts again and recovers the potential difference (roughly) equal to the EMF of the battery.

Thank you for your answer.
